# Two reports in one with a if odoo15 qweb-pdf

Tags: qweb, odoo-15

I'm trying to extend a report with another one. If an if is true, the part should be loaded from another template and filled with the appropriate data. Maybe someone can give me a tip how I can implement this. Unfortunately I'm not getting any results at the moment. Only the initial report is printed.

```
<template id="a_report_order`your text`">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                      ....  
                    </div>
                    <t t-if="checkuppaper_bool">
                        <t t-call="a.b_report_checkup">
                            <t t-foreach="self.env['a.checkup'].search([('partner_id', '=', 'partner_id')])"
                               t-as="doc"/>                            
                        </t>
                    </t>


                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
```